# How to catch all messages from Google Chats into our custom service with a hangout bot?

Tags: google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I wanna collect all messages from corporate google chats into my third party service. As soon as the message appears into the chat it should be send to our third party service. The only opportunity that I have found is to use hangouts bot which executes callback "onMessage" every time when message appears into the chat. In according of the specification this callback will be executed only if the message will be sent to the bot directly or bot's name will be mentioned in the message body. How can I catch all messages from our corporate chats?